# Android Dagger2 Dependency Cycle Error? Why

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Why I am getting dependency cycle error:

```
error: [Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle:
public abstract interface AppComponent {
```

I have this repository. I can remove ILogoutService dependency and it works ok then.

```
 ^

class AuthRepository
@Inject constructor(
    private val service: IAuthService,
    private val logoutService: ILogoutService,
    private val app: Application,
    private val prefs: SharedPreferences
) : IAuthRepository {
```

But this IAuthService and ILogoutService are independent retrofit service dependencies one uses token for bearer authentication.

```
@Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAuthService(@Named(BASIC) retrofit: Retrofit) : IAuthService {
        return retrofit.create(IAuthService::class.java)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideLogoutService(@Named(AUTHENTICATED) retrofit: Retrofit): ILogoutService {
        return retrofit.create(ILogoutService::class.java)
    }
```

They are created with Named Retrofits!

and this retrofits with Named clients, etc.

Retrofit provides

```
@Singleton
    @Provides
    @Named(AUTHENTICATED)
    fun provideAuthRetrofit(@Named(API_BASE_URL) baseUrl: String, @Named(AUTHENTICATED) httpClient: OkHttpClient,
                            converter: GsonConverterFactory, adapter: CallAdapter.Factory) : Retrofit {

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(httpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(converter)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(adapter)
            .build()
    }
```

and

```
@Singleton
    @Provides
    @Named(BASIC)
    fun provideRetrofit(@Named(API_BASE_URL) baseUrl: String, @Named(BASIC) httpClient: OkHttpClient,
                        converter: GsonConverterFactory, adapter: CallAdapter.Factory): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(httpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(converter)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(adapter)
                .build()
    }
```

UPDATE

I've something like this

> public abstract interface AppComponent {
>                   ^
>         com.softnew.crm.api.ILogoutService is injected at
>             com.softnew.crm.repository.AuthRepository(…, logoutService, …)
>         com.softnew.crm.repository.AuthRepository is
>   injected at
>             com.softnew.crm.di.modules.NetworkModule.provideAuthHttpClient(…,
>   repo)
>         @javax.inject.Named("AUTHENTICATED") okhttp3.OkHttpClient is injected at
>             com.softnew.crm.di.modules.NetworkModule.provideAuthRetrofit(…,
>   httpClient, …)
>         @javax.inject.Named("AUTHENTICATED") retrofit2.Retrofit is injected at
>             com.softnew.crm.di.modules.ServiceModule.provideLogoutService(retrofit)
>         com.softnew.crm.api.ILogoutService is injected at
>             com.softnew.crm.di.modules.RepositoryModule.provideAuthRepository(…,
>   logoutService, …)
>         com.softnew.crm.repository.IAuthRepository is injected at
>             com.softnew.crm.ui.authentication.AuthenticationViewModel(…, repo)
>         com.softnew.crm.ui.authentication.AuthenticationViewModel is injected at
>             com.softnew.crm.di.injectable_viewmodel.ViewModelModule.bindContactsViewModel(contactsViewModel)
>         java.util.Map,javax.inject.Provider>
>   is injected at
>             com.softnew.crm.di.injectable_viewmodel.ViewModelFactory(creators)
>         com.softnew.crm.di.injectable_viewmodel.ViewModelFactory is injected at
>             com.softnew.crm.di.injectable_viewmodel.ViewModelModule.bindViewModelFactory(factory)
>         androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
>             com.softnew.crm.MainActivity.viewModelFactory
>         com.softnew.crm.MainActivity is injected at
>             dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.softnew.crm.di.AppComponent →
>   com.softnew.crm.di.ActivityModule_ContributeMainActivity.MainActivitySubcomponent]
>   The following other entry points also depend on it:
>         dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.softnew.crm.di.AppComponent →
>   com.softnew.crm.di.ActivityModule_ContributeMainActivity.MainActivitySubcomponent
>   →
>   com.softnew.crm.di.FragmentBuildersModule_ContributeAuthenticationFragment.AuthenticationFragmentSubcomponent]

I've also tried to inject other repositories into this AuthRepository like UseRepository which also uses Services that uses Retrofit @Named(AUTHENTICATED) instead of @Named(BASIC) and then also I have this cycle dependency!

Comment: Could you attach code you provide Retrofit?

Comment: Have you used the annotations @ Component & @ Module in your code?

Comment: Can you post the full error output?  It should say exactly where the circular dependency is.

Comment: I posted error from console

Comment: O I think i see this I inject AuthRepo into OKHttpClient to get bearer token!